java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Certificate chaining error
Estoy desarrollando una clase java que tiene un método que llama a un Webservice de SOAP:
private String llamarWS(String soapXml) {
        String xmlRespuesta = "";
        try {
            KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
            InputStream keyStoreStream = new FileInputStream(Constantes.FICHEROP12);
            keyStore.load(keyStoreStream, Constantes.PASSWORDP12);
            SSLContext sslContext = SSLContexts.custom().loadKeyMaterial(keyStore, Constantes.PASSWORDP12).build();
            HostnameVerifier hostnameVerifier = new HostnameVerifier() {
                @Override
                public boolean verify(final String hostname, final SSLSession session) {
                    // TODO Apéndice de método generado automáticamente
                    return hostname.equals(Properties.getLexnetHostname());
                }
            };
            
            SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslsf = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(
                    sslContext, new String[] {"TLSv1.2", "TLSv1.1", "TLSv1"}, null,
                    hostnameVerifier);
            
            HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost(Properties.getLexnetProxy(), 8080);
            
            RequestConfig config = RequestConfig.custom()
                    .setProxy(proxy)
                    .build();
            Registry<ConnectionSocketFactory> socketFactoryRegistry = RegistryBuilder.<ConnectionSocketFactory>create()
                    .register("https", sslsf)
                    .register("http", PlainConnectionSocketFactory.getSocketFactory())
                    .build();
            
            PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager connectionManager =
                    new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager(socketFactoryRegistry);
            
            try (CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.custom().setDefaultRequestConfig(config)
                    .setConnectionManager(connectionManager)
                    .build()) {
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(Properties.getLexnetUrlEndpoint() +
Constantes.LOGINSERVICIOSGENERAL);
                httpPost.setHeader("SOAPAction", "");
                httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=UTF-8");

                StringEntity stringEntity = new StringEntity(soapXml);
                httpPost.setEntity(stringEntity);
                xmlRespuesta = EntityUtils.toString(client.execute(httpPost).getEntity(), "UTF-8");
                
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
                    }

En una clase Main() me funciona correctamente. Pero desde un servidor local (utilizo Websphere Aplication Server) me da el siguiente error en la linea
xmlRespuesta = EntityUtils.toString(client.execute(httpPost).getEntity(), "UTF-8");

[10/06/24 16:25:48:613 CEST] 000000b8 SystemErr     R
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: com.ibm.jsse2.util.h: PKIX path
building failed:  java.security.cert.CertPathBuilderException:
PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl could not build a valid CertPath.; internal
cause is:   java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: The
certificate issued by OU=AC RAIZ FNMT-RCM, O=FNMT-RCM, C=ES is not
trusted; internal cause is: 
    java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Certificate chaining
error

En la consola administrativa del servidor he añadido el certificado raíz en Seguridad -> Gestión de claves y certificados SSL -> Almacenes de claves y certificados -> NodeDefaultTrustStore -> Certificados de firmante pero todavía sigue fallando.
¿Podéis ayudarme?
Muchas gracias
Un saludo.

Tienes que descargar y añadir el certificado correspondiente al almacén de certificados (cacerts) del JDK que estés utilizando (%JAVA_HOME%/jre/lib/security). Aquí podrás encontrar una explicación de los pasos a realizar.

Entiendo que se puede añadir más de un certificado en el mismo cacerts, correcto?

Mientras esto en teoría responde a la pregunta, es preferible incluir las partes esenciales de la respuesta aquí y dejar el link (que mañana podría estar roto) como referencia. Te invito a leer [answer].

Conseguido: había que añadir los certificados en el fichero cacerts que viene en el Websphere por defecto.
